# C# Attempting to find a specific menu type

Tags: c#, menu

I'm kinda new to C#,
I'm trying to figure out what kind of container can I use in order to create a menu that behaves like a dropdown menu which will contain set of horizontal buttons for an app.
Possibly one of the closest things to what I'm trying to achieve is the behavior of the "sub menus" like 'Private Networks' / 'Guest or public networks' in Windows Firewall main menu. (except of text it will contain set of buttons)

Images for example:
[image: Menu closed]

[image: Menu Opened]

Would really appreciate if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Create a button (the arrow) and a panel, when the button is clicked toggle the size of the panel.

Comment: Are you using WinForms? WPF?

Comment: @BJ Myers I'm using WPF

Comment: @EBrown have not thought about that, I'll give it a try, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

For some reason when I first went over the controls of WPF I did not see the expander control, this solves everything.
Thanks for the assist